# Button on title of ChildWindow (Silverlight) design issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I'm designing Silverlight ChildWindow and I met one intersting problem. I defined a button on a window title as follows:

```
<ChildWindow.Title>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="This is textblock" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button Content="Help" Name="btnHelp" Grid.Column="1" Width="100"
                Margin="300,0,0,0" />
    </Grid>
</ChildWindow.Title>
```

This window is resizable. When you try to resize the window, the "btnHelp" button is covered by the close button, and the "btnHelp" button is not aligned to the edge of the window also. I tried before to use a StackPanel, also I used margins in both variants (StackPanel and Grid) and they didn't help me properly. The variant in the code is latest:) Could you please give a hint, what can I do with that?
Thanks in an advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of what appears to be a strange choice in the [`ChildWindow`'s control template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833070%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) -- the `Title` content is not stretched, so you can't really right-align anything without hard-coding it.  So, you could go ahead and just apply fixed widths to the Grid column widths:

```
<controls:ChildWindow.Title>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="This is textblock" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button Content="Help" Name="btnHelp" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</controls:ChildWindow.Title>
```

That's quick-and-dirty, but not very satisfying.  An alternative would be to modify the ControlTemplate (at the link above) so that it behaves how you would expect.  Find the `ContentControl` that displays the `Title`, and make it stretch to fill the available space, by adding `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ChildWindow" x:Key="MyChildWindowStyle">

    <!-- etc ... -->

    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" FontWeight="Bold" 
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" Margin="6,0,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <!-- etc ... -->
</Style>
```

This allows you to use the normal layout controls like `Grid`, and it will render as expected:

```
<controls:ChildWindow Style="{StaticResource MyChildWindowStyle}"
    ...
    <controls:ChildWindow.Title>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="This is textblock" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Button Content="Help" Name="btnHelp" Grid.Column="1" Width="100"/>
        </Grid>
    </controls:ChildWindow.Title>
```

[image: Child Window (modified control template)]

Comment: Works for me as I expected. Thank you very much!